# Can CSS grid be used when each row is wrapped in its own container div?

Tags: css, css-grid, css-tables

I currently have a simple table with a main container (i.e. `display: table`). In that container I have some rows (i.e. `display: table-row`), which then have some divs (i.e. `display: table-cell`).

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.table .table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table .table-row div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div>Name</div>
    <div>Phone</div>
    <div>E-mail</div>
    <div>City</div>
    <div>Last meal</div>
    <div>Number of meals</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div>John Doe</div>
    <div>12 34 56 78 910</div>
    <div>mail @mail.com</div>
    <div>Moscow</div>
    <div>1. June 2020</div>
    <div>13</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div>Roger John Doe</div>
    <div>12 34 56 78 910</div>
    <div>myothermail @myothermail.com</div>
    <div>New York</div>
    <div>1. September 2020</div>
    <div>102</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div>Roger Rabbit John Doe</div>
    <div>12 34 56 78 910</div>
    <div>mymail @mymail.com</div>
    <div>London</div>
    <div>1. May 2020</div>
    <div>55</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can a CSS grid be used to achieve this same layout, without removing the `div` which wraps the contents of each row?

I have tried defining a grid on each row. In this case, if you shrink the window, the cells start to collapse, and are no longer aligned with the cells below.

```css
.row-header,
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  font-size: 13px;
  justify-content: start;
}

.row-header div,
.row div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-header">
  <div>Name</div>
  <div>Phone</div>
  <div>E-mail</div>
  <div>City</div>
  <div>Last meal</div>
  <div>Number of meals</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>John Doe</div>
  <div>12 34 56 78 910</div>
  <div>mail @mail.com</div>
  <div>Moscow</div>
  <div>1. June 2020</div>
  <div>13</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>Roger John Doe</div>
  <div>12 34 56 78 910</div>
  <div>myothermail @myothermail.com</div>
  <div>New York</div>
  <div>1. September 2020</div>
  <div>102</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div>Roger Rabbit John Doe</div>
  <div>12 34 56 78 910</div>
  <div>mymail @mymail.com</div>
  <div>London</div>
  <div>1. May 2020</div>
  <div>55</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, any table-like layout can be accomplished using css-grid, but your question is a little vague; i'm not quite sure what you're looking for. you say you got it "somewhat" working -- maybe you can post that half-working code and explain exactly what isn't working that way you thought it would work?

Comment: or just a quick sketch of how the cells should be laid out.

Comment: I have now updated my OP with a fiddle, where you should be able to see the problem.

Comment: i've voted to re-open this question because the OP has added a verifiable example, and the focus of the question is now apparent.

Comment: the short answer is: you've defined a new grid for each row. you want one big grid containing all the rows. here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/xof3hdyj/ -- i'll post a full answer when this question is re-opened.

Comment: Yes, I can see that it can be done with just filling up a grid-based div with a lot of elements, and then setting the size of the rows. However, I am kind of thinking a bit on media queries as well. For example, one option going from tables (which doesn't work well on mobile) is to transform each row into some kind of card. This transformation can be easily done if each cell is inside a row - i.e. the row becomes the card. But if you have every cell inside one parent div, this is not as straight forward - or at least not that pretty, compared to changing from `display: table` to `grid`.

Comment: i see -- if having the container div for each row is important, i think sticking with css-table is the right thing to do. grids aren't made to operate on nested structures, they only operate on their direct children. and having a separate grid for each row is not going to work unless you used fixed sizes.

Comment: i've just made a fairly substantial edit to the question; i believe it gets more to the root of your question and may help this get re-opened. i think this is a valuable question and deserves to be answered. @Denver, if you disagree with my edits, please feel free to roll them back or edit them further.

Comment: Ah, that's fine by me. Probably makes more sense now. But yes, unfortunately it seems like the only solution (if you want it this way at least) is by using tables, and then wait until `subgrid` arrives in more browsers. If I am not mistaken, with this you will be able to achieve what I am asking.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: Not yet.**

CSS grids only operate on their direct children; each direct child is a cell within the grid. You can nest grids, but the nested grid's tracking (i.e., alignment of rows and columns) has no relation to its parent's tracking.

This shortcoming was anticipated when CSS-grid was introduced in the [CSS Grid Layout Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) specification. The [`subgrid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid) feature will address this shortcoming, and will be introduced in [CSS Grid Layout Module Level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-2/), which is currently in "working draft" status.

Firefox (v71 or newer; current stable release is v78) is currently the only browser to include support for CSS subgrid. Others will soon follow, as the specification matures.

The code snippet below demonstrates how the subgrid *will* work. This example works in Firefox today.

This example defines a grid with 6 columns and an automatic number of rows. Each row is wrapped in a container div, and that div spans all 6 columns of the parent grid, just like a table would do. The subgrid is defined in the column direction, meaning all of the parent grid's columns that are spanned by the subgrid become the column definitions for that subgrid.

```css
.grid {
  /* the parent grid. */
  display: grid;

  /* this grid has 6 equally sized columns. */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.grid .row {
  /* a subgrid is just a nested grid whose column
   * and/or row definitions are based on its parent. */
  display: grid;

  /* this subgrid spans from the first column to the
   * last column of the parent grid. */
  grid-column: 1 / -1;

  /* this means that the subgrid's column
   * definitions are based the parent's columns
   * that we spanned.
   * this is the part that isn't well-supported
   * in browsers yet. */
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell">Name</div>
    <div class="cell">Phone</div>
    <div class="cell">E-mail</div>
    <div class="cell">City</div>
    <div class="cell">Last meal</div>
    <div class="cell">Number of meals</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">John Doe</div>
    <div class="cell">12 34 56 78 910</div>
    <div class="cell">mail @mail.com</div>
    <div class="cell">Moscow</div>
    <div class="cell">1. June 2020</div>
    <div class="cell">13</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Roger John Doe</div>
    <div class="cell">12 34 56 78 910</div>
    <div class="cell">myothermail @myothermail.com</div>
    <div class="cell">New York</div>
    <div class="cell">1. September 2020</div>
    <div class="cell">102</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">Roger Rabbit John Doe</div>
    <div class="cell">12 34 56 78 910</div>
    <div class="cell">mymail @mymail.com</div>
    <div class="cell">London</div>
    <div class="cell">1. May 2020</div>
    <div class="cell">55</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**For now, CSS tables are the best way to accomplish a grid/table layout if you need your cells to be nested in the markup.**

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.table div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.gridspan2{
  grid-column: span 2;
}

code{
  background-color: #bbb;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div>Name</div>
  <div>Phone</div>
  <div>E-mail</div>
  <div>City</div>
  <div>Last meal</div>
  <div>Number of meals</div>

  <div>John Doe</div>
  <div>12 34 56 78 910</div>
  <div>mail @mail.com</div>
  <div>Moscow</div>
  <div>1. June 2020</div>
  <div>13</div>

  <div>Roger John Doe</div>
  <div>12 34 56 78 910</div>
  <div>myothermail @myothermail.com</div>
  <div>New York</div>
  <div>1. September 2020</div>
  <div>102</div>

  <div>Roger Rabbit John Doe</div>
  <div>12 34 56 78 910</div>
  <div class="gridspan2">mymail @mymail.com (This cell has <code>grid-column: span 2</code> on it</div>
  <div>1. May 2020</div>
  <div>55</div>
</div>
```

Like that, yes

But you can NOT have rows in CSS grid. You can, however, define `grid-column: span 2` on a cell to combine 2 regular cells.